# How to make an action for all list(array) items?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, list

I tried to create simple monitoring tool for ping all my services in config file. To run a ping command at the same time for all items. At the moment I can ping an individual element by index, how can I do this for everyone?

config/host.yml

```
    default:
      server:
        port: 3000
      hosts:
        type: 'CaP AC'
    development:
      hosts:
      type: 'CaP AC'
      model: 'RBcAPGi-5acD2nD'
      location: 'Office'
      list:
        - host: '10.10.10.10'
          user: 'admin'
          password: 'password'
          name: 'cap-1'
        - host: '10.10.4.5'
          user: 'admin'
          password: 'password'
          name: 'cap-2'
```

controller/update.js

```
const Hosts = require('./hosts');
const Monitor = require('ping-monitor');

module.exports = {
  Ping: function (config) {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          config.hosts.list.forEach(cap => {
              let pong = new Monitor({
                  website: "http://"+config.host,
                  interval: 1,
                  config: {
                      intervalUnits: "seconds"
                  },
                  ignoreSSL: true
              })
              pong.on('up', function (res, state) {
                  console.log('Service up!');
              });

              pong.on('error', function (error, res) {
                  console.error(error);
              });
          })
      })

  }
```

controller/hosts.js

```
var hosts = [];
module.exports = hosts;
```

index.js

```
const config = yaml_config.load(__dirname + '/config/host.yml');
const Update = require('./controllers/update');
const Hosts = require('./controllers/hosts');

Update.Ping(config).then(result => {
  result.forEach(cap => {
      console.log(cap +result)
  }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
  });
})
```

Comment: Your question is not very clear. If I understood correctly, you want to ping all hosts with a single ping-monitor instance. This is not possible, as the package does not support that kind of interface. Either way, the package would anyway need to send a separate request per host.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap each monitor in a promise and await all those promises before you print the received status. Here's some sample code that should help you:

```
module.exports = {
  Ping: function (config) {
        const monitorPromises = config.hosts.list.map(currConfig => {
            return new Promise((resolve) => {
                const currMonitor = new Monitor({
                    website: "http://" + currConfig.host,
                    interval: 1,
                    config: {
                        intervalUnits: "seconds"
                    },
                    ignoreSSL: true
                });
                currMonitor.on('up', function (res, state) {
                    resolve(`${res.website}:${res.port} is up.`);
                });

                currMonitor.on('down', function (res) {
                    resolve(`${res.website} is down!, statusMessage:  ${res.statusMessage}`);
                });

                currMonitor.on('stop', function (res, state) {
                    resolve(`${res.website} monitor has stopped.`);
                });

                currMonitor.on('error', function (error, res) {
                    resolve(error);
                });

                currMonitor.on('timeout', function (error, res) {
                    resolve(error);
                });
            });
        });
        console.log("done");
        return Promise.all(monitorPromises);
    }
};
```

Then in your caller, you can do:

```
Update.Ping(config).then(monitors => {
  monitors.forEach(result => {
      console.log(result);
  }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
  });
})
```

Comment: @sdvjke: any feedback?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your example. Very interesting. A strange story really comes out. I am still testing. As a result, hosts with a down status are returned.

Comment: Well, can you reach the hosts through a ping command on your terminal? Also can you try changing the hosts to something like e.g. `google.com`? If it works with those, the issue has definitely noting to do with above nodejs code, rather something related to infrastructure.